# Insert a column into a table which tells me the count of amount of employees in each department -- postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am stuck on a problem and cannot seem to understand why it is not working. I have some tables, the tables of importance are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE departments 
(
    department_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    department_name CHARACTER VARYING (30) NOT NULL,
    location_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) 
        REFERENCES locations (location_id) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE employees 
(
    employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name CHARACTER VARYING (20),
    last_name CHARACTER VARYING (25) NOT NULL,
    email CHARACTER VARYING (100) NOT NULL,
    phone_number CHARACTER VARYING (20),
    hire_date DATE NOT NULL,
    job_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    salary NUMERIC (8, 2) NOT NULL,
    manager_id INTEGER,
    department_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES jobs (job_id) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (department_id) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

First I updated the table and inserted the necessary column which was :

```
ALTER TABLE departments
    ADD COLUMN no_of_employees numeric;
```

and then tried to get the count of employees in each department using this query:

```
SELECT department_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM employees
JOIN departments ON departments.department_id = employees.department_id
GROUP BY employees.department_id, departments.department_name;
```

Which forks fine and produces this output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tsQC.png)

But when I try add this column into my `no_of_employees` column it says I am returning to many columns and is just giving me the complete wrong answers so I would appreciate any help if possible. I can't find any similar threads online.

```
UPDATE departments
SET no_of_employees = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS empCount
                       FROM employees e
                       JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
                       WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
                       GROUP BY e.department_id)
```

> Error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> Error Code: 21000

Comment: Lose the departments table join inside your Select.  Instead, `Update departments  d` and retain the `WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id`.

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY, just have a correlated subquery,

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Yes this worked perfectly, but I don't understand why. Any chance you could explain why this was causing a problem? No problem if not! Thanks alot for the solution

Comment: The query inside your update does not connect to anything in the departments table.  So the updater pulls out the first department,  it runs your query which returns all the department counts and does not know how to connect 35 department counts to the row it is working on.  Error.  Also, see my answer below for a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I always find this kind of mass update easier to do with the newer Merge statement than with Update, and this particular update case implies you will run your Count query once for each department unless the query optimizer is quite good.

```
Merge Into departments d
Using (Select department_id, count(*) as empcount
       From employees
       Group By department_id) e
  On d.department_id=e.department_id
When Matched Then Update Set d.no_of_employees=e.empcount
When Not Matched Then Update Set d.no_of_employees=0
```

A little verbose, but it's easier to see what is going on, the data retrieval does not default to a correlated subquery, and it automatically handles the no employees case correctly.